# Virtual machines hard disks sizes can be larger than the available datastore capacity?

Tags: vcenter

I am quite new in VMWare VCenter Lab Manager. Can it be that the total summary of a Virtual Machines hard disk sizes are larger then the capacity of the datastore?

For example I would like to have a datastore with 1000 GB storage capacity and I would like to run 6 virtual machines under this datastore: 5 Virtual Machines with 100 GB hard disk and the 6th with 800 GB.
Is this situation possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but only with 'thin disks'. Doing so is called over provisioning and is not recommended in most scenarios.